# Desligar case sensitive no Postgres

Tags: postgresql, sensibilidade-de-caixa

Quando eu faço o comando `select * from tabela where name like '%teste%'` a linha com o name `TesTe` retorna, porém o mesmo não acontece no postgres, eu não quero colocar `lower(name)` para funcionar, como posso desativar o case sensitive em uma coluna?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Para realizar uma busca no Postgres desconsiderando  maiúsculas ou minúsculas, basta trocar o `like` por `ilike`

Sua busca fica assim:

```
select * from tabela where name ilike '%teste%'
```

Answer (score 7):

Além do operador `like`, conforme o Denis apontou temos também as expressões regulares no *PostgreSQL*, que facilitam muito as buscas e permitem "desligar" o case sensitive. Para entender melhor vamos usar a tabela abaixo de exemplo:

```
# ------------+-----------
#    name     | username
# ------------+-----------
#  Joao Pedro | Joaopedro
# ------------+-----------
#  joao pedro | joaopedro
# ------------+-----------
# (2 linhas)
```

### **Expressões Regulares:**

> Uma expressão regular (ou Regex) provê uma forma concisa e flexível de
>   identificar cadeias de caracteres de interesse, como caracteres
>   particulares, palavras ou padrões de caracteres.

A sua diferença em relação ao `like` é justamente essa, você possui uma capacidade maior de busca, podendo buscar por padrões ou cadeias de caracteres, diferentemente do `like`, que possui limitação para busca complexas em caracteres.

Para utilização de Expressões Regulares, se faz necessário conhecer alguns meta caracteres que são encontrados na utilização do Regex. Não vou mostrar eles aqui, mas vale o [aprendizado](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-matching.html).

Aqui embaixo estão os operadores de expressão regular.

- `~` - Corresponde à expressão regular, diferenciando maiúsculas e minúsculas;
- `~*` - Corresponde à expressão regular, não diferenciando maiúsculas e minúsculas;
- `!~` - Não corresponde à expressão regular, diferenciando maiúsculas e minúsculas;
- `!~*` - Não corresponde à expressão regular, não diferenciando maiúsculas e minúsculas.

Vamos ver um exemplo onde queremos procurar pela palavra 'Joao Pedro' dentro da nossa tabela. Repare que na busca queremos buscar pela string sem diferença de caracteres maiúsculos e minúsculos.

```
SELECT name FROM <tabela> WHERE name ~* 'Joao Pedro'

-- Retorno:

# ------------|
#    name     |
# ------------|
#  Joao Pedro |
# ------------|
#  joao pedro |
# ------------|
# (2 linhas)
```

Não tenho certeza, minha opinião, mas acredito que ao procurar sem diferença de maiúsculas e minúsculas o banco de dados coloca a palavra desejada para minúsculo e vai em cada registro colocando a palavra do mesmo em minúscula e comparando para ver se é igual a desejada.

### **Operador like:**

O `like` é muito conhecido e dispensa apresentações. Para usar o `like` em suas consultas sem diferença de maiúsculas e minúsculas basta usar o operador `ilike`. Pense assim para facilitar:

- `like` - *Sensitive* (Sensível)
- `ilike` - *Insensitive* (Insensível)

Veja a seguinte consulta:

`SELECT name FROM users WHERE name ilike 'joao pedro'`

Ela irá retornar o mesmo resultado que a do exemplo de expressão regular. A sua única diferença está no operador.

### **Performance - Expressão regular vs like:**

A performance é relativa a cada situação. Caso tenha uma busca complexa utilizar expressão regular vai facilitar muito a busca e trazer muito mais performance para a *query*. Caso precise apenas fazer uma busca simples, de, pequenas palavras ou apenas por um nome o `like` pode ser um grande aliado.